# CSV export is not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, export-to-csv, scrapy

This is my spider class:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import csv

class StackItem(scrapy.Item):

    job_role = scrapy.Field()
    company = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
    read_more = scrapy.Field()


class newJobSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "newFlaskSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["placementindia.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://jobs.placementindia.com/lucknow"]
    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*\?id1=.*',),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="prevNext next"]',))
, callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        posts = hxs.select("//article[@class='classified']")
        items = []

        for post in posts:
            item = StackItem()
            item["job_role"] = post.select("div[@class='uu mb2px']/a/strong/text()").extract()
            item["company"] = post.select("p[1]/text()").extract()
            item["location"] = post.select("p[@class='mb5px b red']/text()").extract()
            item["desc"] = post.select("details[@class='aj mb10px']/text()").extract()
            item["read_more"] = post.select("div[@class='uu mb2px']/a/@href").extract()enter code here
            items.append(item)

            for item in items:
                yield item
```

And this is item pipeline

```
class myExporter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('output6.csv', 'wb'))
        self.myCSV.writerow([item['job_role'], item['company'], item['location'], item['desc'], item['read_more']])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.myCSV.writerow([item['job_role'], item['company'], item['location'], item['desc'], item['read_more']])

        return item
```

When they are in separate class, running fine. I am getting results in csv file. Due to my project requirement, i need the csv exporter class inside the spider definition. How can these classes be combined??

Comment: You can nest class definitions in Python.

Comment: Will you please elaborate that how i can use nested class structure in this scenario????

Comment: I meant you could put the `myExporter` class definition inside of the one for the `newJobSpider` class.

Comment: then how to access items of 'newJobSpider' class inside 'myExporter' class? Just by making an object of super class and accessing its variables is not working. I mean 'newJobSpider.items' is not producing any results under 'myExporter' class.

Comment: It's not clear from the code you posted what the `item` references in the two `myExporter` methods is. The way it's written they must be globals for it to have worked. If they're attributes of a `newJobSpider` _instance_ then it will have to be passed as an argument to each of them.

Comment: I think instead of looking at nested classes, you should explain *why* one you need to nest the classes.  This goes against Scrapy's project-layout, as there is no support for loading a pipeline from a nested class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this problem:

**1) Why nesting a class?**

If you have to nest the exporter in the spider `class` itself it should not be nested. And there is no need for a separate exporter. Because if you have your exporter nested you should access it from the spider. This means you should use your spider to write the items to a CSV file so you do not need to yield any `item`s from your `parse_items` method in this case -- but implement the `process_item` method there. So no need for a separate exporter.

**2) Exporter in the same file than the spider**

If you have your exporter in the same file as your spider, you have to point to this exporter `class` from your `settings.py` file. Imagine your project is located in the `new_job` folder, the Python file of your spider is called `newjob.py`. In this case you can add the following line in the `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'new_job.spiders.newjob.myExporter' : 90,}
```

By the way when I copied your code then I've had some errors which I needed to fix. So I wonder if it ever worked for you.